# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\pi Rx)}{R(\pi x)^2}dx$ for $R>0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\pi Rx)}{R(\pi x)^2}dx$$ for $R>0$. 
The value is $1$, but I don't know which integration technique I need to use to calculate this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Integral over all of the real line?

Comment: @WillM. Yes over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Assume $a>0$. One may differentiate
$$
I(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^2 (ax)}{x^2}\:dx
$$ obtaining
$$
I'(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin (2ax)}{x}\:dx=2 \cdot \frac{\pi}2=\pi
$$ giving
$$
I(a)=\pi a
$$ since $I(0)=0$, then take $a=\pi R$ to evaluate the given integral.

Answer (score 2):

An idea: put

$$u=\pi Rx\implies dx=\frac{du}{R\pi}\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2R\pi x}{R(\pi x)^2}dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{R\sin^2u}{u^2}\frac{du}{R\pi}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2}du=1$$